# Scala worksheet can not resolve class name - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I am following along with a lecture, the lecturer is using Eclipse but I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.6, and the code on a Scala worksheet named rationals.scala is as follows

```
object rationals{
  val x = new Rational(1,2)
  x.numer
  x.denom
}

//noinspection ScalaPackageName
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
  def numer = x
  def denom = y
}
```

The Scala worksheet worksheet will not compute and there is a warning (not error) associated with the class definition that reads

> Package names doesn't correspond to directories structure, this may
>   cause problems with resolve to classes from this file

Also, and this is odd but maybe significant, IDEA flags numer and denom as typos.

Any guidance? thx

Comment: Isn't `object rationals` supposed to be a companion for `class Rational`? In other words, isn't there a typo? If you want for object to be a companion for the class, their names should match.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with the name matching directory structure, the actual problem is that you have multiple definitions in the worksheet which it doesn't like. If you declare the `class` inside the `object`, then it'll compute properly:

```
object rationals {
  class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
    def numer = x
    def denom = y
  }

  val x = new Rational(1,2)
  x.numer
  x.denom
}
```

[image: IntelliJ worksheet]

Comment: That works but I do not think that is the same thing for 2 reasons, (1) instructor demo in Eclipse does not embed class definition inside object scope but it still works, and (2) I should be able to move the class definition to a new file, Rational.scala, within the same package and reference it in the worksheet however this does not work either for same reason as original problem.

Comment: @MaxWen If you reference `Rational.scala` outside the worksheet, then you have to make sure to tick the `Make project` box the first time you run it. Eclipse and IntelliJ worksheets don't work the same.

Comment: I am selecting this as the correct answer although I think there is something more going on.  In Eclipse when you create a new worksheet foo, the new worksheet opens and object foo{} is already present.  However IntelliJ opens a blank worksheet.  I am thinking this indicates a difference between implementations.

Answer (score 3):

@Yuval Itzchakov @MaxWen

If you reference `Rational.scala` outside the worksheet, then you have to **make sure to tick the Make project box** the first time you run it.

Eclipse and IntelliJ worksheets don't work the same. –